# How to calculate the percentage of similarity of two arrays of different length in php

Tags: php, arrays, compare, percentage, similarity

I have retrieved records of two users from a database in two arrays respectively. The records are of people who follow other people just like in twitter.
Since two users may be following different number of people. So the length of the two arrays is different. i have created a new array that stores the common people ( people followed by both users).
How can I get % similarity of the two users. Lets say if two users have 5 common followers they have more similarity than 2 users having 2 in common.

```
foreach($common as $row){
//do events
echo $row['name']."<br>";
$count_common++;
}
echo "total common ".$count_common;
$similarity = (count($common)/(count($user1_follows))*100);
```

The above formula does not calculate correct result since it is based for arrays having same length.
Here is a related question to mine [get the percentage of similarity of two arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298371/get-the-percentage-of-similarity-of-two-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 10):

```
$p1 = array("foo", "bar", "grep");
$p2 = array("foo", "buzz", "fizz", "bar");
$similar = array_intersect($p1, $p2);
$p1_perc = count($similar) / count($p1); // 0.66..
$p2_perc = count($similar) / count($p2); // 0.5
```

To get one number:

```
$perc = 2 * count($similar) / (count($p1) + count($p2)); // 0.5714..
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,You have calculated the % similarity of each arrays. What I want is to find the % similarity of both the arrays in one constant number. For e.g UserA has 75% similarity with UserB , UserC has 10% similarity with User D. Like this .

Comment: Just average the 2 numbers. You could also do a squared average or a logarithmic one. The method you chose will depend on the underlying mathematical principle. This is beyond my understanding.

Comment: answers like this is what makes stackoverflow so cool :) thanks @FritsvanCampen

Comment: By average the 2 numbers, did you mean to take average the two percentages ? $p1_perc and $p2_perc ?

Comment: What if you simply did `($p1_perc+$p2_perc)/2 ? would that work

Comment: Well, it seems that `2 * sim / (p1 + p2)` is **not** the same as `avg(sim / p1, sim / p2)`. I'm sure some math buff could explain which is the right one.